# Why ought I not use 'hope' passively, if it has a subject?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: Rebecca Gowers. [*Plain Words* (2014 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plain-Words-Rebecca-Gowers/dp/0241960347). p. 228 Bottom.

> *Hope* should not be used in the passive except in the impersonal phrase *it is hoped*. We may say [1.] "It is hoped that payment will be made next week", or [2.] "payment is expected to be made next week", but not **[3.] "payment is hoped to be made next week"**. The phrasal verb *hope for*, being transitive, can of course be used in the passive.

If 2 is acceptable, then why isn't 3?

Comment: You mean something like, *"That I get a pony for my birthday **is hoped** by me"*?  Because it doesn't sound very good.  Just use the active tense.  I suppose it works in some contexts, although *it is hoped* is more common.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. But your example doesn't feel the most charitable? I prefer 3 overhead. Or 'Winning the lottery is hoped by [lengthy nouns].'

Comment: A few verbs like "hope, decide, prefer", are restricted to extraposed position: "It was decided to accept the offer", but not *"To accept the offer was decided". And "It was hoped to be a big success", but not *"To be a big success was hoped". Don't ask me why - it's just the way the language has evolved.

Comment: Extraposed position is preferred when there is an infinitive complement.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to learn what is acceptable with all of these verbs of desire and request (prefer, wish, hope, want, wish, demand, ask, request, etc).

> They preferred payment to be made in Euros. <sup>yes</sup>
>
> Payment they preferred to be made in Euros.  <sup>yes</sup>
>
> Payment is preferred to be made in Euros.  <sup>marginal or no</sup>
>
> Payment to be made in Euros they preferred.  <sup>no</sup>
>
> It is preferred that payment is|be made in Euros. <sup>yes</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule it's sound to say that you should not use *hope* in the passive tense.  Consider the awkward example:

> That I get a pony for my birthday **is hoped** by me

Nevertheless I disagree that you can *never* use it.  Because it is an awkward circumlocution, it can add a deliberate (possibly ironic) twist by enhancing whatever nuance the passive tense implies:

> That he be exposed for the charlatan he is, **is hoped** by many.

In this case the sentence emphasizes the particular turn of phrase, *he be exposed as the charlatan he is*.  Of course it might be more natural to say:

> **It is hoped** by many that he be exposed for the charlatan he is.

but, because it is natural, it doesn't carry the same nuance.